# overflow auto, scroll, property is not working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow, behance-api

I found this Theme which I've really fallen in love with.

[start bootstrap template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/)

I want to make my Portfolio website with this theme but here is the few changes I want it to make it happen.

When you click any of those thumbnails, other image will pop out right, which is the main image that you want it to showcase. I want that image to be big, maybe **1280 px and overflow auto or scrollable**

I gave parent `div` overflow property **auto**, but it didn't work. Then, I changed to **scroll**, still not working

Here is the HTML:

```
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter popup-gallery">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center portfolio_text_padding">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Portfolio</h2>
                <hr class="light color">
                <p class="text-faded portfolio">
                    Portfolio time another word it is time to showcase the work.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="img/portfolio/bkg.png" class="portfolio-box" >
                    <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

So the image I what to put inside of those thumbnails is 1400px by 2000px and the idea I got this from [behance](https://www.behance.net/)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Here in this fiddle you can give it a try

http://jsfiddle.net/x58RD/

```
#mydiv {
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

Replace the URL in the HTML with this: http://abduzeedo.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_cover/public/originals/wpw_1400px.jpg?itok=IeiXQvLh

and then click run

Hope this will help out :) 
Let me know